# Query Builder "OR" in dynamic query

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-query

I would like to build a query with clause "OR" and the query receive an array parameter and doesn't know how elements it contains.

The query has to return a list of contents that have the category "1" or "2"(if $categ array contain [1,2]) etc.
Category is a foreign key in the content entity.

My repository:

```
   public function getContentOfSomeCategories($categs)
    {
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');

        $conditions = [];
        foreach($categs as $value){
            $conditions[] = 'c.contentCategory = '.$value;
        }

        $orX = $query->expr()->orX();
        foreach ($conditions as $condition) {
            $orX->add($condition);
        }
        $query->add('where', $orX);
```

I obtain the error message "Too many parameters: the query defines 1 parameters and you bound 2".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From PHP 5.6 onward, you can probably use PHP splat `...` to expand an array to arguments.

```php
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');
        $expr = $query->expr();

        $conditions = [];
        $valueNo = 0;
        foreach ($categs as $value) {
            $conditions[] = $expr->eq('c.contentCategory', 'value'.$valueNo);
            $query->setParameter('value'.$valueNo, $value);
            $valueNo++;
        }
        $query->andWhere($expr->orX(...$conditions));
```

Disclaimer: I've not tested this.

See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

> You can also use ... when calling functions to unpack an array or Traversable variable or literal into the argument list:

**Edit:**

If your query is simple, you could just use `orWhere` instead.

```php
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');
        $expr = $query->expr();

        $valueNo = 0;
        foreach ($categs as $value) {
            $query->orWhere($expr->eq('c.contentCategory', 'value'.$valueNo));
            $query->setParameter('value'.$valueNo, $value);
            $valueNo++;
        }
```

**Edit 2:**

You might even want to just use an `in` clause instead.

```php
$query->where($expr->in('c.contentCategory', ':values'));
$query->setParameter('values', $categs);`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this quite easily, below utilises the query builder expression builder:

```php
$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');

$conditions = [];

$i = 0;

foreach ($categs as $value) {
    $i++;

    $conditions[] = $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('c.contentCategory', $i);
    $queryBuilder->setParameter($i, $value);
}

$queryBuilder->andWhere(
    $queryBuilder->expr()->orX()->addMultiple($conditions)
);
```

If you parameter applies to all then you can just add

`$queryBuilder->setParameter();`